# Remove duplicates in a file

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing

I have the following file.txt

```
Plummet
Cherist the day
--
The Transatlatins                <-----------duplicate
Mysteriosa                       <-----------duplicate
--
Angel City;Lara McAllen
Love me right                  
--
The Transatlatins
Mysteriosa
```

How can I delete duplicates without changing the order? and the spaces of line, I have tried with `sort` but I change the order and`uniq` does not take me the duplicates.

expected result:

```
Plummet
Cherist the day
--
Angel City;Lara McAllen
Love me right               
--
The Transatlatins
Mysteriosa
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `uniq` only works on a sorted input.

Comment: I don't see any duplicate lines in your file (other than empty lines). I double the question, what is your expected result?

Comment: There are no true duplicates here. Assuming the fields are artist, album and track, then the repeat of `Mysteriosa` is missing a field. Or you only want to match on 2 fields and ignore the 3rd?

Comment: The duplicate line is `The Transatlatins` (and the empty ones)?

Comment: Kinldy post expected output

Comment: I want the file to be without deleting the duplicates the document has 15000 lines of songs separated by a space

Comment: For the example segment you've shown us please indicate what you consider to be duplicate,  and therefore what you would expect as output.

Comment: Please clarify Freddy's question above about 'The Transatlatins' also apparently being a duplicate. I'm also curious if you can specify that the *last* duplicate is the one that you want to keep (since you seem to have removed the first instance of 'Mysteriosa'.  Also, you've added extra `\n`'s to the sample output; do you really need those?

Comment: I want all the duplicates in the text to be deleted, except the original that only one remains so that the songs do not repeat themselves

Comment: The latest edit still has two "Transatlatins" entries...?

Comment: `--` is also a duplicated line

Comment: all but the original are deleted only those that are repeated so it stays:
The Transatlatins
Mysteriosa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** that the file is intended to be in the format

```
field1\n
field2\n
\n
field1\n
field2\n
\n
```

i.e. the last line in the sample file should read

```
Mysteriosa                  Mysteriosa
```

then this should do the trick, provided there is a trailing newline `\n` after the last entry

```
sed '$!N;$!N;s/\n/:/g' file | nl -s"|" | sort -t '|' -k2 | awk -F"|" '!_[$2]++' | sort -n | sed -e 's/.*|//' -e 's/:/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
awk '{if (!seen[$1,$2]++)print $0}' filename
```

Comment: You might add some explanation about how this removes duplicates, exactly.  It'd be good if we knew what the OP wanted, exactly, before attempting solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty nice answer! I never tried awk on this way. But I suggest to follow what the mod said, I think he is right.